# I have a text file that each number needs to be put into an array

Tags: c#, arrays, quicksort

We were given a text file that randomly generates ~500 numbers.  I have the file read, but now I want to store it into an array so that I can sort it from least to greatest.  Every time I try and set it up I get a bunch of different errors.
Here is what I have so far.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {

            //opens and closes the stream reader
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("sort.txt"))
            {
                string line;
                while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(line);

                }
            }
        }

        catch (Exception e)
        {
            //lets user know that the file could not be read
            Console.WriteLine("Sorry that file could not be read");
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
```

Do I need to set up the array in the try statement?  What do I need to do to sort these numbers?

Comment: "I get a bunch of different errors." What errors? It looks like you have several things to think about: 1) Converting each line into a number; 2) storing those numbers (I'd use a `List<T>` rather than an array); 3) sorting. Do you have to implement the sort yourself? Which of those steps is causing a problem? Please ask one question about the specific part you're having trouble with.

Comment: Okay first question.  Do I have to take line and convert it to int32?

Comment: Well that's probably the simplest approach, yes. Look at `int.Parse`.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what errors do you get, but if you need simply read numbers from file (assuming one integer per line), it can be done in the following way:

```
var myNumbers = File.ReadAllLines("myFile.txt")
                        .Select(x => int.Parse(x))
                        .OrderBy(x => x)
                        .ToList();
```

Comment: If you're using LINQ already, why not use `OrderBy`? Also, you can use `.Select(int.Parse)` rather than a lambda expression. But I suspect that all this is a little too advanced for the OP, who is probably new to the language.

Comment: @nikis That is identical to my solution - you beat me to it. :) But I agree with Jon Skeet; using OrderBy makes sense.

Comment: @JonSkeet @Ulric ok, changed to `OrderBy`. Method group is definitely a little too advanced.

Answer (score 0):

Posting information about your errors would be helpful in resolving those specific issues.

However, for the array specifically if you know it will always be 500 numbers you can simply declare an array of integers and use it as follows:

```
int[] numberArray = new int[500];
numberArray[i] = int.Parse(line); //Assuming you can rely on them always being numbers
```

Having said this I think a normal List and Linq might be the preferred way to accomplish some of this. Though I will save that example for now.

I will try to add more info if you can provide more details.

Edit: Adding List info:

At the very top of your program you will need this:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
```

It tells the compiler you wish to use code from that assembly and it is where the List class resides.

Next just declare your list:

```
List<int> numberList = new List<int>();
```

Then as you loop through your file you can add your integers to the list:

```
numberList.Add(int.Parse(line));
```

And when you are ready to sort them you will need to add this to the top of your program:

```
using System.Data.Linq;
```

And then in your code you can create a new list that has your sorted numbers:

```
List<int> sortedListOfNumbers = numberList.OrderBy(p => p).ToList();
```

Or if you just want to loop through and print them out:

```
foreach( int number in numberList.OrderBy(p => p)) {
    Console.WriteLine(number);
}
```

Comment: Okay using a list would be easier? Never really had to use it before.  Can I  use the stream reader to put line into a list?

Comment: @secretlygayfrog: You wouldn't put the line into a list - you'd parse each line and add the `int` to a `List<int>`.

Comment: Yep.  In your case something like List<int> numberList = new List<int>(); would declare your list and then numberList.Add(int.Parse(line)); would parse the number into an int and save it in the list.  Note that you will need to include a using for using System.Collections.Generic; to be able to reference the namespace that List<> resides in.  Or if you are in Visual Studio (particularly recent editions) you should be able to declare the list and right click on the List<int> type and select Resolve->using System.Collections.Generic;

Comment: OK - Updated the answer to include some of the info above plus the added information about how to use Linq to sort them.  All of this is essentially what the answer above by Nikis is telling you, I just went through and broke it down into pieces so you can follow what is happening at each step.